# Setting the minimum and maximum values of category axis of line chart from kendo ui in jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-chart

When I set the min and max in the categoryAxis in kendo line chart. I got an an error. In this case I temporarily set static dates but even if I dynamically set it, the same error happened.

Code in front end:
Pls. see the categoryAxis: min and max.

```js
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: { text: "MyChart" },
                theme: "Metro",
                dataSource: dataSeries,
                series: [{
                    type: "line",
                    field: "value()",
                    categoryField: "Date",
                    name: "#= group.value #"
                }],
                legend: {
                    position: "right"
                },
                valueAxis: {
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                categoryAxis: {                    
                    min: new Date("6/2/2017"),
                    max: new Date("7/3/2017"),
                    baseUnit: "days",
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    labels: {
                        rotation: 40,
                        padding: { right: 10 },
                        dateFormats: {
                            days: "M/d/yy"
                        },
                        step: step
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I load the chart, got this error from kendo js.

Error from kendo js.:

```js
VM2938:3 Uncaught TypeError: d.value is not a function
    at eval (eval at getter (kendo.all.js:2048), <anonymous>:3:11)
    at n (kendo.all.js:142386)
    at init._bindFromObject (kendo.all.js:141977)
    at init.bindPoint (kendo.all.js:141936)
    at r._bindPoint (kendo.all.js:142838)
    at r.traverseDataPoints (kendo.all.js:142802)
    at render (kendo.all.js:142432)
    at render (kendo.all.js:143397)
    at r.init (kendo.all.js:142429)
    at new r (kendo.all.js:42)
```

Comment: Could you reprodcuce your example in Kendo Dojo?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `categoryAxis`, set the `type` attribute to `"date"`, as per the example in the [Telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.type).

E.g.

```
categoryAxis: {                    
    min: new Date("6/2/2017"),
    max: new Date("7/3/2017"),
    type: "date",
    baseUnit: "days",
    majorGridLines: {
        visible: true
    }, 
    labels: {
        rotation: 40,
        padding: { right: 10 },
        dateFormats: {
            days: "M/d/yy"
        },
        step: step
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciated your idea @Sandman thanks. But,same error happened.